# Houston Meteor Admin Package denies admin access

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the Houston Meteor Admin Package but after I use it in my application:
Once I create account, I get this message

> You are not an Admin. If you need to use the Houston Admin, please ask your Admin to grant you access.

What is wrong?

Comment: You should be able to "claim" the admin role if you visit the `/admin` route. If that doesn't work, maybe there's already an admin user? Try to visit the `/admin` route with different users

Comment: Thanks @Julien. Yes I did when I go the http://localhost:3000/admin/login : I am given an option to create a new account. Once I do that I am not given admin grant. I get the message that says :" You are not an Admin. If you need to use the Houston Admin, please ask your Admin to grant you access." There is a claim button followed by this which is does not work either. Is there something I am missing out ? I saw a git article that suggested to drop the admin collections. I did not find any luck yet.

Comment: Are you connected with a user ? Any console output ? Perhaps there's some validation constraint on the user that prevent from adding the role (Simple Schema?). Just guessing there, I've used it recently and it worked properly so there's a chance that your app is responsible.

Comment: Do you suggest any changes that I have to do in my application with respect to validating constraints. I tried with the same project as well from the online tutorial I referred to but still I get the same validation error. Completely confused with this. It would be great if you can share your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :

Add the check package :

meteor add check

This will solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the route `/admin` in your browser to claim admin.

Comment: Thanks @Eliezer. Yes I did when I go the /admin : I am given an option to create a new account. Once I do that I am not given admin grant. I get the message that says :" You are not an Admin. If you need to use the Houston Admin, please ask your Admin to grant you access." There is a claim button followed by this which is does not work either.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/admin/login  - This is the link that directs me to the create account page